Tsibble autoplotting forecasts shows warning, doesn't show prediction intervals
I'm working through Forecasting: Principles and Practice 3rd Ed., but I'm running into strange issues when applying the principles in actual code. Here's a simple forecast using data mentioned in the book:
library(tsibble)
library(tsibbledata)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(fable)

races <- olympic_running %>% 
  filter(Length < 1500, Sex == "men")

races %>%
  model(TSLM(Time ~ trend())) %>%
  forecast(h = 1) %>%
  autoplot(races,
           level = c(80,95))



I'm getting a bunch of warning messages:
Warning messages:
1: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x, na.rm = na.rm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

I don't know what these max and min functions are checking, and most of all I can't figure out why the prediction intervals aren't being drawn. This happened with other data used in the book, this is just the latest I'm working with.
I'm using the latest versions of all listed packages, but I can't think of another reason why using the code doesn't provide expected results. What can I try to change?
